# Software to find the common volume of intersecting cylinders?

Tags: computer-aided-design

I would like to find the common volume between cylinders for different radii and at different angles (3-D). Can I do this using ANSYS design modeller? Or what can I use (preferably a free download for a student please) and how long would it take to compute one solution?

I essentially would like to create a lookup table for the common volume between different cylinders that look like this for example.
[image: cylinders]
Thank you for your help!

Comment: This sounds like something you could do with Excel?
If you really want to work in 3D space, any software that can do boolean operations will work - Fusion 360 springs to mind re: free for students.

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to all of this, how would you do it on Excel?

Comment: The volume of a standard Tricylinder is $V=8(2-\sqrt{2})r^3$ - you can calculate the formulae for other situations using relatively basic maths. Can you provide some diagrams/images showing what sort of shapes you're actually looking at?

Comment: N.B. If you go the Excel route, this would be better suited at the Math Stack Exchange - if you stay here, you're at risk of being too vague - software recommendation isn't really our 'thing', I'm afraid

Comment: Thank you, I have added a picture now above. Ah I have looked at formula but for the different radii and different angles, it gets quite complicated so I think I will need a design software so I can find the volume for particular cases as I cannot find a general solution. Would this best be done using fusion? Thank you!

Comment: See this paper for the case where the two cylinders are infinitely long. 
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e8a1/00e42c4a79f959bc1000be619c00dd5f939a.pdf

Comment: Hi I can do the case for two cylinders, but when it comes to 6 for different radii and angles it gets a lot more complicated and I cannot solve it myself! Unless you know papers for more cylinders? Thank you